# Convert Contains To Expression Tree

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees, c#-6.0

Related To: [Create a Lambda Expression With 3 conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032599/create-a-lambda-expression-with-3-conditions)

Please consider this Code:

```
from a in myTbl
where a.Address.Contains(strToCheck)
select a
```

How I can convert this to Expression Tree and write above code with Expressions?
Main Problem is converting `a.Address.Contains(strToCheck)` to `Expression Tree`.

Edit 1) Address is a **`string`** field and `strToCheck` is a **`string`**

Thanks

Comment: What is difference between convert `.Select()` to expression tree and `.Contains()` to expression tree? Nothing. So if you know how to convert `Select` you should know how to convert `Contains`.

Comment: Thanks. But l'm new to Expression trees and there isn't many and good resouce for it. If you know the answer please help me

Comment: SO contains many examples how to write expression tree that invokes some method, as example `Any` `Where` and many also. You can check a few examples: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45887790/access-childrenlist-related-property-in-expression-tree) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45765350/create-predicate-with-a-binaryexpression-containing-multiple-parameters). Main idea is that you create `MethodCallExpression`  from corresponding `MethodInfo`. By the way, why do you want to convert your example to a `ExpressionTree`?

Comment: It depends of what is the type of `a.Address` - you either need to call `string.Contains` or `Enumerable.Contains`.

Comment: @George Alexandria please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673032/create-generic-abstract-class-using-ef-database-first-approach   I should use `T` and I haven't access to `T` properties

Comment: I understand why you want to convert. So try to convert it to expression by yourself as pointed out in the comments above and edit your question if you still have a few issues.

Comment: @George Alexandria Thanks but I can't convert it to Expression Tree. I realy don't know from what point I should start. I'm very confused

Comment: Well, if you really want to get full answer you need to explain what is the `Address`. See comment from ***Ivan Stoev***

Comment: @George Alexandria  I update my question

Comment: Please, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46392672/need-help-converting-any-lambda-to-an-expression-tree). I think it will very helpful for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a.Address.Contains(strToCheck)` represents a *call* to [`string.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) *instance method* on `a.Address` *instance* with `strToCheck` *argument*.

The simplest way to build the corresponding expression is to use the following [`Expression.Call` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336138(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static MethodCallExpression Call(
    Expression instance,
    string methodName,
    Type[] typeArguments,
    params Expression[] arguments
)
```

like this (using the terms from the linked question):

```
var body = Expression.Call(
    Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "Address"), // instance
    "Contains", // method
    Type.EmptyTypes, // no generic type arguments
    Expression.Constant(strToCheck) // argument
);
```

Comment: it is EXCELLENT. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the type of myTbl,
So I have created a simple solution using just a list of objects.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var adresses = FilterByAddress("Address", new List<Person> { new Person { Address = "Address1" }, new Person { Address = "AAAAAA" } });
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Person> FilterByAddress(string strToCheck, List<Person> list) {
            var listParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<Person>), "list");
            Expression<Func<Person, bool>> contains = a => a.Address.Contains(strToCheck);
            var select = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Single(m => m.Name.Equals("Where") && m.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType.GetGenericArguments().Length == 2);
            var genericMethod = select.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(Person) });
            var call = Expression.Call(null, genericMethod, new Expression[] { listParam, contains });
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<Person>, IEnumerable<Person>>>(call, new[] { listParam });

            return lambda.Compile().Invoke(list);
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If you want to use a filter by predicate you can pass an `Expresssion<Func<Person, bool>>` as parameter (one line)

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var strToCheck = "Address";
        var list = new List<Person> { new Person { Address = "Address1" }, new Person { Address = "AAAAAA" } };
        var adresses = FilterByAddress(list, p => p.Address.Contains(strToCheck));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Person> FilterByAddress(List<Person> list, Expression<Func<Person, bool>> predicateEx) {
        var listParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<Person>), "list");
        var select = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Single(m => m.Name.Equals("Where") && m.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType.GetGenericArguments().Length == 2);
        var genericMethod = select.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(Person) });
        var call = Expression.Call(null, genericMethod, new Expression[] { listParam, predicateEx });
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<Person>, IEnumerable<Person>>>(call, new[] { listParam });

        return lambda.Compile().Invoke(list);
    }
```

In case you have a very compilicated predicate which spans to multiple lines (an expression tree can be evaluated from a one line lambda) you can use a trick to construct an expression tree out of the predicate Func like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var strToCheck = "Address";
        Func<Person, bool> predicate = p => {
            return p.Address.Contains(strToCheck);
        };

        var list = new List<Person> { new Person { Address = "Address1" }, new Person { Address = "AAAAAA" } };
        var adresses = FilterByAddress(list, predicate);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Person> FilterByAddress(List<Person> list, Func<Person, bool> predicate) {
        var listParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<Person>), "list");
        Expression<Func<Person, bool>> predicateEx = p => predicate(p);
        var select = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Single(m => m.Name.Equals("Where") && m.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType.GetGenericArguments().Length == 2);
        var genericMethod = select.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(Person) });
        var call = Expression.Call(null, genericMethod, new Expression[] { listParam, predicateEx });
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<Person>, IEnumerable<Person>>>(call, new[] { listParam });

        return lambda.Compile().Invoke(list);
    }
```

Using the generic approach to filter a list by predicate

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var strToCheck = "Address";
        Func<Person, bool> predicate = p => {
            return p.Address.Contains(strToCheck);
        };

        var list = new List<Person> { new Person { Address = "Address1" }, new Person { Address = "AAAAAA" } };
        var adresses = FilterBy<Person>(list, predicate);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> FilterBy<T>(List<T> list, Func<T, bool> predicate) {
        var listParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<T>), "list");
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicateEx = p => predicate(p);
        var select = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Single(m => m.Name.Equals("Where") && m.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType.GetGenericArguments().Length == 2);
        var genericMethod = select.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(T) });
        var call = Expression.Call(null, genericMethod, new Expression[] { listParam, predicateEx });
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>>>(call, new[] { listParam });

        return lambda.Compile().Invoke(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: You call that a **simple** solution? Some explanation of the used code would be nice.

Comment: Thanks I will test it. Please consider @Flater comment

Comment: This line: `Expression<Func<Person, bool>> contains = a => a.Address.Contains(strToCheck);` I want to implement this code with parameter. I haven't access to `Address` property because I used generic abstract class and my entity is just `T`

Comment: Another consideration is I want pass `Expression<Func<Person, bool>>` to a function that filter data in database level.