# Need help converting "Any()" lambda to an expression tree

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, tree, expression

Consider the following. (which works, but I need Accounts to be passed in as a string. Accounts is list of Account)

```
repo = repo.Where(x => x.Accounts.Any(p => p.Id == 1));
```

Here is what I have so far, but I can't seem to wire them together at the end.

```
        var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Car), "x");
        Expression propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, "Accounts");

        //Type elementType = propertyExp.Type.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        MethodInfo AnyMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).First(m => m.Name == "Any");

        var parameterExp2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Car), "p");

        var idExpr = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExp2, "Id");

        MethodInfo method = typeof(long).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(long) });
        var _relatedToId = Expression.Constant(relatedToId, typeof(long));
        var equalsMethodExp = Expression.Call(idExpr, method, _relatedToId);

        // This is where it breaks. I can't seem to wire it together correctly.
        var call = Expression.Call(
            AnyMethod,
            propertyExp,
            equalsMethodExp);

        Expression<Func<Car, bool>> predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Car, bool>>(call, parameterExp);

        // Need to return x => x.Accounts.Any(p => p.Id.Equals(1))
        return predicate;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain what is type of `x` and `p`

Comment: x is of type Car and p is of type Account where "Accounts" is a list of Account. i.e. MyCar.Accounts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a several mistakes:

- Firstly, uncomment line below

  ```
  Type elementType = propertyExp.Type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
  ```
- Secondly, you don't correctly retrieve `MethodInfo` for `Any`. You need info that contains two parameters (source, func) and you need to get the closed type of Any `Any<Account>` not the open `Any<>`:

  ```
  MethodInfo AnyMethod = typeof(Enumerable)
                         .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                         .First(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.GetParameters().Length > 1);
  var closedAnyMethod = AnyMethod.MakeGenericMethod(elementType);
  ```
- Third, you have incorrect type for `parameterExp2`. It should be `Account` not `Car`:

  ```
  var parameterExp2 = Expression.Parameter(elementType, "p");
  ```
- Fourthly, you should convert a `MethodCallExpression` for *Equals* method to lambda expression. You cannot directly pass *Equals*' call expression to `Any` because `Any` gets `Func<T, bool>` as parameter:

  ```
  var equalsMethodExp = Expression.Call(idExpr, method, _relatedToId);
  var lambdaAny = Expression.Lambda(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(elementType, typeof(bool)), equalsMethodExp, parameterExp2);
  ```
- Finally, you just need to call another override of `Expression.Call`:

  ```
  var call = Expression.Call(
          closedAnyMethod,
          propertyExp,
          lambdaAny);
  ```

Let me know if you want to get the complete code.

Comment: This is really close. Accounts is being passed in as a string. Car is the only known type at run time. I've been getting the Account type from Type elementType = propertyExp.Type.GetGenericArguments()[0]; This gives Type Account. Everything works up until the lambdaAny var lambdaAny = Expression.Lambda<Func<Account, bool>>(equalsMethodExp, parameterExp2); typeof(elementType) doesn't seem to satisfy Func.

Comment: Can you give more info what's wrong with `var lambdaAny = Expression.Lambda<Func<Account, bool>>(equalsMethodExp, parameterExp2);`? It's compilte or runtime error or it's just doesn't work correct? Can you post how is represented `equalsMethodExp` in the debug? Does It seem like this: `{p.Id.Equals(1)}`?

Comment: Account in your example is a concrete type as you have it. I don't now what Account is going to be at compile time. The type will change. I need something like Expression.Lambda<Func<UnknownType, bool>>(equalsMethodExp, parameterExp2); Unless I have a concrete type in Func, it won't build. equalsMethodExp has the correct value

Comment: @th3monk3y Please check answer, I edited it. Now type is retrieved in the runtime from `propertyExp`. If you want you can pass it from somewhere.

Comment: Works!! Thank you so much George!